# Is there a performance benefit/penalty when adding int-values to doubles?

Tags: c++

Given a vector addition:

```
  NPNumber NPNumber::plus(const double o) const {
    vector<double> c;
    for (double a : values)
       c.push_back(a + o);

    return NPNumber(width, c);
  }
```

Where NPNumber contains a vector of doubles (field values), when I only add a single integer, instead of another NPNumber, is there a performance benefit or penalty compared to converting that integer and using the function above?

i.e., is this faster/slower on any architecture:

```
  NPNumber NPNumber::plus(const int i) const {
    vector<double> c;
    for (double a : values)
       c.push_back(a + i);

    return NPNumber(width, c);
  }
```

Comment: N.B. `vector<double> c(values.size());` creates a vector with `values.size()` default-initialized elements (value `0`), then `push_back` adds *additional* elements after them. Maybe you want to use `reserve` instead?

Comment: You are right. This was just a stupid copy&paste error from another method. As the allocation is not of interest here, I removed it completely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's strongly compiler depended and you should measure it in your code. A quick and simple observation in my machine (32-bit MinGW/gcc 4.9) shows the `+` itself is equal for both cases, however the integral operation seems a little better.

Adding two `double`:

```
!        double d = 0.2;
fldl   0x409070
fstpl  -0x10(%ebp)

!        double y = 1.0;
fld1   
fstpl  -0x18(%ebp)

!        double z = d + y;
fldl   -0x10(%ebp)
faddl  -0x18(%ebp)
fstpl  -0x20(%ebp)
```

Adding two `int`:

```
!        double d = 0.2;
fldl   0x409070
fstpl  -0x28(%ebp)

!        int y = 1;
movl   $0x1,-0x2c(%ebp)

!        double z = d + y;
fildl  -0x2c(%ebp)
faddl  -0x28(%ebp)
fstpl  -0x38(%ebp)
```

Both use `faddl` to add, but compiler uses better instruction to load the integer before adding. So, there is no penalty to add an integer to a double (and it may be even better rather than adding two doubles).

In your application, profiling is the best way to find out that which one is better.

Answer (score 2):

Another thing to consider is compiler optimizations.

Floating point units tend to have their own registers.  These in some cases may even have greater precision than typical operands (for instance, 80-bit temporary reals;) however, see the comments as this can vary a lot.

I would expect it is cheaper to operate on values already loaded into the FPU, and the compiler should know this.  As such, it may hoist the promotion of your constant value out of the loop and keep the value loaded in the FPU, in which case the difference would be negligible on large vectors.

In any event, I would hope that if the `int` to `double` conversion is expensive on a given platform, a respectable compiler would not perform it redundantly.  As such, what I'd probably do is make it a template method so you can accept whatever type & precision the constant data naturally comes from; this permits the compiler to "do the right thing" for the particular platform in any given situation.

With that said, compilers do vary quite a bit in their optimization strategies and platforms vary in their features & performance characteristics, so if you're trying to squeeze out every last microsecond, you should do profiling for your platform(s) of interest.

Comment: The FPU stack is a peculiarity of the x87 architecture, and I don't think any other architecture suffers from it. Other FPUs, including x86 SSE, generally use registers. But the conclusion is still relevant: the `int` to `double` conversion can be hoisted if the result can be saved effectively in the FPU.

Comment: @MSalters: Thanks for the tip about the FPU register files; fixed that.

Comment: Oh, and FP registers usually do not have greater precision either. That too is an x87 oddity. In fact, some low-end chips have only lower precision (float in hardware, double requires software)

Comment: @MSalters: Sounds like I need to get out and see more FPUs.  :-)